# Filling Array List with random data

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have the following variables and `ArrayList`:

```
int rowLength, columnLength;
ArrayList<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

I need to fill this array list with random data. The data must be string (recommended `int` that has been converted to `String`). The main goal is to fill multidimensional array list with random data.

I've tried to do that but I had too many troubles. I'm new in Java, so sometime I need help with basic things as well.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I'll write you the answer

Comment: Please post what you have tried and and what went wrong

Comment: I will try to post my code. The problem is that i did too many attempts, so i need to post the most stable version. It will take some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use nested for loops like below:

```
int rowLength = 10, columnLength = 5; //Initialize sizes
ArrayList<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();

for (int row = 0; row<rowLength; row++) {
    String[] stringsColumn = new String[columnLength];
    for (int col = 0; col <columnLength; col++) {
        stringsColumn[col]=Integer.toString(col);
    }
    data.add(stringsColumn);
}
```

**Output loop**

```
//Note that this output loop will interchange the columns for rows but it works fine for demonstration
for (String[] col:data){
    for (String s:col){
        System.out.print("\t"+s);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

**Output**

```
0   1   2   3   4
0   1   2   3   4
0   1   2   3   4
0   1   2   3   4
0   1   2   3   4
0   1   2   3   4
0   1   2   3   4
0   1   2   3   4
0   1   2   3   4
0   1   2   3   4
```

Comment: Did you try execute this code? Looks to me this will throm ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: `stringsColumn[col]=Integer.toString(col)`.

Comment: I had a typo in the initialisation of the stringcolumn, I have corrected it. Do you still get the error?

Comment: It is not problem in compile time - this code you can compile, there is not typos. 
There is error when you execute this code. I tried. 
The problem is this `stringsColumn[col]` - you try access to index 5, and array length is 5. Because that it throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Sorry I did't mean spelling typo, I had used `new String[rowLength];` instead of `new String[columnLength];`. Check to see if you used the correct variable in the `stringsColumn` array's length.

Comment: I have copied/pasted you code, and it has thrown ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. There is logical error at line 7: `stringsColumn[col]=Integer.toString(col);` The reason for this error is in your for loop, your index `col` starts from 5 - and thah is length of array, but indexes in array are 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: It  compiles and runs on my machine for some reason. Let me post a better alternative

Comment: Pleas try execute your code again - it throws the error. 
Alternative, which I will use: 
`for (int col=0; col<columnLength; col++)`, also `for(int row=0; row<rowLength; row++)`
Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [nextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28%29) from Random. This will create a random int which you can wrap in 
 [Integer.toString(int i)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int%29). Then add it to a String[] then add it to the ArrayList.

For example:

```
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < columnLength; i++) {
    String[] s = new String[rowLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        s[i] = Integer.toString(r.nextInt());
    {
    data.add(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
public String generateRandomString(int len) {
    String AB = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    Random rnd = new Random();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        sb.append(AB.charAt(rnd.nextInt(AB.length())));
    return sb.toString();
}
```

And this:

```
public Integer generateRandomInteger(int range) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    Integer val = rnd.nextInt(range);
    return val;
}
```

Having these 2 functions you can add random data to your ArrayList:

```
data.add(generateRandomString(10));
data.add(generateRandomInteger(200));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is many, many, many ways to do this. From what I see from your snippet is that you do expect some static range of this "multi dimenesional" "Array":isch thingy.

```
int rowLength, columnLength;
```

would then imply two dimensions, is that the case or are you expecting more dimensions, is the dimension(s) dynamic? If two is the limit I guess String[][] would do, else some more dynamic construct of Map or List should work.